# Can you please explain cut off ratio as described in Heat and Thermodynamics by Mark W Zemansky and Richard H Dittman

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

[image: Text vook]
This is what said in Heat and Thermodynamics written by Richard H Dittman and Msrk W Zemansky about cut off ratio of Diesel engine. According to Zemansky cut off ratio is $\frac{V_1}{V_2}$ But when I searched web it is found to be $\frac{V_3}{V_1}$.
Is there any way I can relate both. 
Since this is a standard textbook for many universities and a question raised many of my colleagues, I expect someone would answer this question.

Comment: I just saw that my answer has been accepted (by the OP, I suppose). But I got just a handful of reputation points (including some from a few upvotes). Why didn't I get the bounty ?

Comment: Hey ! I just realized that there are, in fact, two misprints in your question ! For the cutoff ratio $r_E$ in the wording of your question you write that according to Zemanski it is $V_1/V_2$, but in the book it is written $V_1/V_3$, still incorrect, but not what you wrote. Then you write that you found on the web $V_3/V_1$, also incorrect, but in the book you amended in brown to $V_3/V_2$, which is indeed correct.

Comment: Fortunately I have trouble reading small characters, so I based my whole reasoning on what was visible in the book, namely Zeamnski's misprint and the correct result in brown, without really reading the formulas in the wording of your question... ;)

Comment: Found my misprint, yet ? In my answer, it was accidental, but I left it on purpose. Then I just repeated it in one of my three comments just above, this time on prupose.

Comment: @Alfred The bounty is awarded separately by the user who started it. If they don't award it within the time left, and if you still have the top voted answer by then, you will get the bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a misprint in Dittman and Zeamnsky's book. Even the best books, however often one reads and rereads the proofs, **still** contain misprints.

Comparing (6.6) with the first definition of $\eta$ one sees that

$r_E=T_3/T_2$ from the denominator and

$r_E^\gamma=T_4/T_1$ from the numerator.

Consider the first relation: the evolution from point 2 to point 3 is **at constant pressure**. Therefore the volumes are proportional to the temperatures, so

$r_E=T_3/T_2=V_3/V_2$

is indeed correct.

Now imagine the left top part of the picture fixed. The points 2 and 3 are fixed, and thus $r_E$ is fixed. What prevents me from making the two adiabatics longer, or shorter, stopping at whatever value of $V_1$ that I choose (larger than $V_3$) ? Since *the complicated factor in* $\eta$ does not depend on $r_C=V_1/V_2$, there is no contradiction. Whatever value of $V_1$ I end up with, th*is factor in the* efficiency is the same.  Of course this will change $P_0$ but $P_0$ does not appear anywhere !

The second relation, the one from the numerator, involves $T_1$ that does depend on $V_1$ but only through the ratio $T_4/T_1$. It is easy to prove that though both $T_1$ and $T_4$ depend on $V_1$, their ratio does **not**. It depends only on $V_3/V_2$.

Here is the proof. To make things clearer, I use $P_1=P_0$.

The equations of the adiabatics are

$P_4 V_4^\gamma=P_3 V_3^\gamma$

$P_1 V_1^\gamma=P_2 V_2^\gamma$

But $V_1=V_4$, and $P_2=P_3$ so

$P_4 V_1^\gamma=P_2 V_3^\gamma$

$P_1 V_1^\gamma=P_2 V_2^\gamma$

Take the ratios, you find $P_4/P_1=(V_3/V_2)^\gamma$

Now the points 1 and 4 are at the same **volume**. Hence the ratio of the pressures is equal to the ratio of the temperatures. Hence

$T_4/T_1=P_4/P_1=(V_3/V_2)^\gamma=r_E^\gamma$

as expected. $V_1$ does not appear in the ratio $T_4/T_1$ even though of course both $T_1$ and $T_4$ depend on $V_1$.

$V_1$ can be choosen completely arbitrarily, provided it is larger than $V_3$ of course.

Misprints survive in published work, you can take my word for it. I have plenty of misprints in **my** published articles, proofreading is **never** perfect.

Congratulations for finding this one !

Ooops ! There is (at least) one misprint in this answer. I did **not** do it on purpose, it is perfectly a genuine "honest mistake". I reread this post many times and I missed it till now. Since it does not at all affect the reasoning, I'm leaving it for you to find....

EDIT : 
Well, there were (at least) two misprints. The most severe was in fact more than a misprint.  The one I found last I corrected *in italics*.

I had erroneously called $\eta$ the **complicated factor in $\eta$** that depends on $r_E$ but indeed  **not** in $r_C$ or on $V_1$. Of course, $\eta$ itself does depend on $V_1$ (or $r_C$) but **only** through the **simple** factor $T_1/T_2$. Indeed on the adiabatic curve one has

$P_1 V_1^\gamma=P_2 V_2^\gamma$

and thus

$T_1 V_1^{\gamma-1}=T_2 V_2^{\gamma-1}$

so $T_1/T_2=(V_2/V_1)^{\gamma-1}=r_C^{1-\gamma}$

But my reasoning is still correct, I just concentrated on the complicated factor and mistakenly **called** it $\eta$ when it was just one factor in $\eta$. Sorry about that. On the other hand, the same lack of precision is already in the book itself ! It says there that "the efficiency (...) does not depend on $r_C$", and this must be understood as "the complicated factor". The ratio $T_1/T_2$ in the efficiency is not independent on $r_C$ !

The **other** misprint, the one I saw the previous time, I left on purpose. That one **really** has nothing at all to do with the physics involved.